# Dockerfile : RUN results in a No op

Tags: process, docker

I have a Dockerfile, in which im trying to run a deamon that starts a java process.

If I embed the script in the Dockerfile, like so.

```
RUN myscript.sh
```

When I run /bin/bash on the resulting container, I see *no* entries from jps.

However, I can easily embed the script as *CMD* in which case, when i issue

```
docker run asdfg
```

I see the process start normally.

So, my question is, when we start a background async process in a *Dockerfile*, is it always the case that its side effects will be excluded from the container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Background-processes needs to be started at container-start, not image build.
So your script needs to run via `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT`.

`CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` can still be a script, containing multiple commands. But I would imagine in your case, if you want several background processes, that using example `supervisord` would be your best option.

Also, check out some already existing `Dockerfiles` to get an idea of how it all fits together.